# Find files of multiple extensions batch

Tags: batch-file, dir

I'm trying to search for files of multiple under a specific directory.
I know that if I wish to search for all `.exe` files under `C:\Test`, I do the following:

```
set FoundFiles=dir /b /s C:\Test\*.exe
```

But, what I wish to search for all `.exe` and `.txt` files under `C:\Test`? Is it possible in the same way?
I tried the following:

```
dir /b /s C:\Test\*.exe *.txt
```

It works in cmd, however, when I do this:

```
set FoundFiles=dir /b /s C:\Test\*.exe *.txt
```

It doesn't work.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work

```
dir /b /s *.exe /s *.txt
```

Comment: i believe your double `/s` is redundant. Just need to say it once. It means "recursively", and isn't related to the specific extensions. Btw, your edit queue is full. Maybe other people have made the same suggestion.