# CMD dir List video files - Not Found error

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, directory-listing

I crafted some command line code (function? I don't know the technical term, my apologies) that is meant to look in a network folder (and all it's subfolders) and only list the file path for those files that are a particular type. I tried to test it on a folder with less information in it first, however I got the error `File Not Found`. This confused me because I looked in the folder--there were definitely .VOB and .mp4 files in the specified folder.

When I run the code included below, I don't get the error, BUT I'm getting a bunch of files I don't want (.pdf .xml .jpeg--etc.) I think because they're system files such as the .jpeg files for the .avi thumbnails.

```
dir "\\nas-rb4b\projectx2" /s /b *.avi *.mov *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpg *.lnk *.ldb *.rar *.mpeg *.m4v *.vob *.zip>Projx2RERUN.txt
```

Can anyone help me understand why I got the `File Not Found` error when I tried to run the exact same code but with a different more specific folder?

I also don't know how to modify the code/function to exclude files that are not the listed file types and are not system folders. Any help is, as always, much appreciated!

Comment: @KenWhite, well according to the multiple sources I looked at online, yes. Like this link for example: [link](https://www.windows-commandline.com/dir-command-line-options) unless I've grossly misunderstood it

Comment: @KenWhite, if you look lower on the page you will find this: `dir *.docx *.xlsx *.pptx`

Comment: @KenWhite, there is also this text: "We can even specify multiple extension in dir command to list files of any of the types. To list all files created with Office applications like Word, Excel, Powerpoint etc we can run below command." I mean no disrespect, I'm merely confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the newest [`dir` command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) in [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands):

[Syntax:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#syntax)

> ```
> dir [<Drive>:][<Path>][<FileName>] [...] [/p] [/q] [/w] [/d] [/a[[:]<Attributes>]][/o[[:]<SortOrder>]] [/t[[:]<TimeField>]] [/s] [/b] [/l] [/n] [/x] [/c] [/4]
> ```

[Remarks:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#remarks)

> To use multiple `FileName` parameters, separate each file name with a
>   space, comma, or semicolon.

The command in question `dir "\\nas-rb4b\projectx2" /s /b *.avi *.mov *.mp4` 
 (truncated) says and performs the following:

- `dir "\\nas-rb4b\projectx2" /s /b`, (i.e. all files in `"\\nas-rb4b\projectx2"`), then
- `dir /s /b *.avi` (i.e. all `.avi` files in the current directory), then
- `dir /s /b *.mov` (i.e. all `.mov` files in the current directory), then
- `dir /s /b *.mp4` (i.e. all `.mp4` files in the current directory), …

**Solution** (read [`pushd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd) and [`popd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/popd) reference as well):

```
pushd "\\nas-rb4b\projectx2"
dir /s /b *.avi *.mov *.mp4 *.wmv *.mpg *.lnk *.ldb *.rar *.mpeg *.m4v *.vob *.zip>Projx2RERUN.txt
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

Following some advice from [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) along with a combination of the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814470/find-files-of-multiple-extensions-batch), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139719/delete-all-files-of-specific-type-extension-recursively-down-a-directory-using), and information from [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/dir-command-line-options/) I made the expression below which eventually worked for me.

```
dir /b /s \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.avi \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.mov \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.mp4 \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.wmv \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.mpg \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.rar \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.mpeg \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.m4v \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.vob \\nas-rb4b\projectx2\*.zip
```

It is not pretty but it allowed me to search for multiple file types using only one expression and have their paths all sent to one txt file rather than searching each file extension individually.

So far it is working as intended.